# TypeScript function parameter - array or single item

Tags: typescript

In my TypeScript app, I'm using a library function (written in JavaScript), which can return either a `string` (for 1 result) or `string[]` (for several). Is there a way to represent this in TS without falling back on `any`?

At the moment I'm just using `values: string[]` but that doesn't properly represent the possibility of a scalar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TypeScript 1.0, there is no simple way for modeling a function that has varied return types that are not compatible (you can define an `interface` For example that returns objects that share a common base type, but an array and a string do not).

You'll need to use `any` to represent the returned values.

You might follow and vote up [this](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1364) on CodePlex which is a suggestion to implement something like a Type Union.

Comment: Thanks, CodePlex issue upvoted, the `var a: string|string[];` is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that if the type or number of arguments passed in control what the output will be. This is because TypeScript supports function overloading. For example :

```
declare function a():number;
declare function a(f:number):number[];


var foo = a(); // number
var bar = a(123); // number[]
```